# Why is the Google Apps Marketplace UpgradeableApp API returning this response on a successful upgrade?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I'm in the process of writing a script to upgrade an old OAuth 1 listing to a newer OAuth 2 listing in the Google Apps Marketplace. I've successfully linked the old listing to the new one and upgrading it via my script is possible. However, the response I'm getting on a success case is...strange.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v1migratev2#step_4_invoke_the_api_method), the response should have an `upgrade_status` field, with either `SUCCESS` or various failure statuses. Instead, the response.body looks like this on a success:

```
{"kind":"appsmarket#upgradableApp"}
```

When I have the user check out their Google Apps admin panel, everything seems to have worked. The discrepancy between the docs and the actual response is a bit concerning though. Why is this happening?

Comment: What is the scope that you have used to run the upgradeable API?